# How to insert Many Button handlers in Dynamic table in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am making Notice admin page using JQuery. and I want to attach buttons(edit, remove) at each list item. how to control each button or how to insert the handling function?  Also, I should respectively edit/remove using JSON. any better idea? code below.

> $.getJSON('listnotice.php', function(data) {

```
  $.each(data, function(index,entry) {

        table += '<tr>';  
        table += '<td>' +entry["content"] + '</td>';        
        table += '<td><button class=edit id=' + index + '>edit</button><button id=remove>remove</button></td>';
        table += '</tr>';
    });

    $("#noticeList").append(table)

    $('.edit').click(function() {

        alert('Handler for .click() called.');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Live() instead of click().

```
$('.edit').live('click',function() {

    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Comment: .live() is deprecated. Even if the OP wasn't planning to use 1.7 (and the .on() function) yet, it's still both more performant and more future-proof to use .delegate() (which is superseded but still available in 1.7 when they upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery 1.4.2+, `.delegate()` was preferred over `.live()`.

As of 1.7, you should be using `.on()` instead of `.live()` to accomplish what you want to do.

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.edit', function() { ... }); //to use syntax closer to .delegate()
```

"`#wrapper`" is any ancestor element that is not expected to get destroyed. In your application it might not have the ID "wrapper" but might even be the table element itself, assuming the table in its entirety never gets destroyed.